# executeUpdate returns incorrect value for "INSERT INTO with SELECT"

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement, oracle12c

```
public Integer getCount(){

    PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;
    int count = -1;
    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO TEST(TID) SELECT SID FROM SAMPLE";
        prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        count = prepStmt.executeUpdate(); }
```

1) when select query has only 1 row i'm getting count as zero(0)

2) when select query has 2 rows i'm getting count as 1

3) when select query has 3 rows i'm getting count as 2

it's not inserting the last row in the select query. could someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure your row count of the select be correct?  Did you actually check the record count in the table?

Comment: yes. i counted the select query rows. it's not inserting the last row.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening...something is wrong here.

Comment: @Tim that's what i'm trying to understand.

Comment: Why are you getting a count with an insert statement to begin with? This seems like a convoluted approach.

Comment: OK...when you run the same `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` directly against Oracle, what happens?

Comment: all the rows are inserted when trying manually.

Comment: @Jacob i need the count if not zero to trigger some other operation

Comment: I'll take your word for it, but nothing in your post shows that you need anything but the select statement.

Comment: This sounds unlikely; but are you maybe using an old unsupported or buggy driver? (Also wonder if this is your exact code - could you possibly be doing `count += prep...`, since that is initialised to -1? Just a thought...)